# changing chmod for files but not directories

Tags: unix, grep, chmod

I need to use chmod to change all files recursivly to 664. I would like to skip the folders.
I was thinking of doing something like this

```
ls -lR | grep ^-r | chmod 664
```

This doesn't work, I'm assuming because I can't pipe into chmod
Anyone know of an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested to know that you can make directories executable without making files executable (e.g. `chmod -R +X`, with a capital X).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

A `find -exec` answer is a good one but it suffers from the usually irrelevant shortcoming that it creates a separate sub-process for every single file. However it's perfectly functional and will only perform badly when the number of files gets *really* large. Using `xargs` will batch up the file names into large groups before running a sub-process for that *group* of files.

You just have to be careful that, in using `xargs`, you properly handle filenames with embedded spaces, newlines or other special characters in them.

A solution that solves both these problems is (assuming you have a decent enough `find` and `xargs` implementation):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

The `-print0` causes `find` to terminate the file names on its output stream with a NUL character (rather than a space) and the `-0` to `xargs` lets it know that it should expect that as the input format.

Comment: This is great for GNU find but unfortunately -print0 and xargs -0 are not standard, and don't work e.g. on Solaris.  So in that case use one of the other solutions.

Comment: I can confirm that this method works on Mac OSX (10.9 at least).

Comment: @mark4o, you're not limited to using the braindead versions that come with Solaris. One great advantage of FOSS is that you can port it to any close-enough (UNIXy) OS. I frequently did that for AIX per-version-5L.

Comment: If you mean have too _many_ arguments for `chmod`, that's not an issue. `xargs` batches things up intelligently.

Comment: @paxdiablo You're right. I did not word my comment correctly. Xargs has a maximum command length. If you are using your recommended method, you could hit this limit. It's unlikely, but possible. Check `getconf ARG_MAX` to see this limit.

Comment: this worked great on Mac OS X (10.9). I tried so many things before this.

Comment: well explained, and portable enough for my needs, even if it's not 100% posix

Comment: We might need to set `-L num` option for `xargs` in cases where we have too many files and run into `Argument list too long` issue trying to do a single `chmod` on all of them.

Comment: @codeforester, `xargs` *already* batches up files so that they don't exceed the argument length limit. The `-n/-L` options simply allow further arbitrary limits on the batch size.

Answer (score 37):

Another way to do this is to use `find ... -exec ...` as follows:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

The problem is that the `-exec` starts a `chmod` process for every file which is inefficient.  A solution that avoids this is:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

This assembles as many file names arguments as possible on the `chmod` processes command line.  The `find ... | xargs ...` approach is similar; see the accepted answer.

For the record, using back-ticks is going to break if there are too many files to be chmoded, or the aggregated length of the pathnames is too large.

Answer (score 23):

My succinct two cents...

Linux:

```bsh
$ chmod 644 `find -type f`
```

OSX:

```bsh
$ chmod 644 `find . -type f`
```

This works to recursively change all files contained in the current directory and all of its sub-directories. If you want to target a different directory, substitute `.` with the correct path:

```bsh
$ chmod 644 `find /home/my/special/folder -type f`
```

Comment: how do you specify which directory?

Comment: My original answer covered what the OP had asked about: recursively changing all of files in the current directory. See my edit for how to apply this to any directory, not just the current one.

Comment: Thank you for the simplest and shortest solution

Comment: Fails for me for names with spaces (Mac OS+Bash).

Answer (score 2):

via http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/aix-43/chmod-recursion-files-only-208798/?s=a70210fb5e5d0aa7d3c69d8e8e64e3ed

> "find . -type f -print | xargs chmod 444 "shoud work, isn't it ?
>   If not, find . -print >myfile.sh
>   and vi myfile.sh removing the directories (they should not be soo many), and then
>   1,$s/^/chmod 444/
>   and sh myfile.sh.

Answer (score 2):

with GNU find

`find /path -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +;`