# cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1 Hello World sample doesn't work using cygwin on windows8

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, cocos2d-x

I am unable to build helloWorld sample to get .so to run it in eclipse. I have imported project successfully and changed variable to my root path as required. this is my build_native.sh. I am pasting the only change I made in that file

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL=/cygdrive/e/android-ndk-r8
COCOS2DX_ROOT_LOCAL=/cygdrive/e/cocos2d
```

And my NDK is working fine because I have executed HelloWorld sample of NDK successfully. My SDK version is 20 and NDK version is 8 and I am using cygwin above than 1.7.. I have executed the chown on my NDK directory.. But when I run the command ./build_native.sh in HelloWorld sample program for cocos2d I get this error

```
E:/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-          linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/png.a: No such file: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and when I search for png.a in my NDK directory window can't locate that file. I am confused whether it's a permission error or File isn't there. But I have the latest NDK if file isn't there how come anyone will able to run cocos2d-x??? Need Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the permissions on built files were missing when I tried as well.

```
$ ls -l obj/local/armeabi/png.a
---------- 1 someuser Domain Users 912618 Jul 12 18:23 obj/local/armeabi/png.a
```

There is a [link suggested](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/10/topics/4480?r=4484#message-4484) on the [forum](http://cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/10521?r=10537#message-10537) which doesn't seem to be accessible right now.

Anyway, to fix, you can set the permission on the files.

```
$ cd obj/local/armeabi/
$ chmod 664 *.a
$ cd ../../..
```

**Edit:** A [better fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082542/905908) may be to set the default permissions in /etc/fstab to

`none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,noacl,posix=0,user 0 0`

Following this, you should be able to run `./build_native.sh`.

A command you could use to locate all files below the current directory which have no (read/write) permission available on them is `find . -type f -perm 0`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1163346/905908) to set write permissions on all files below your working directory.

Consider going through a [tutorial](http://catcode.com/teachmod/) on [chmod](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml) to understand the concept of permissions in linux/unix in case you're unfamiliar with them.