# Changing permission of files on searching a directory

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I am trying to search all directories with name 'bin' and change the permission of files under all directories which were successfully found. I tried with the below command:

```
find -type d -name bin -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

But this changed the permission of bin directory. It did not change the permission of the files underlying bin. Please help.

Recursively changing the permission with -R as shown in the solution below is the key. Not the solution provided in the similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing chmod for files but not directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1163294/608639), [How to chmod the files based on the results from find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194878/56041), [How do I set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740152/608639), [Recursively chown all files that are owned by a specific user](https://superuser.com/q/648163/173513), [How to recursively chmod all directories except files?](https://superuser.com/q/91935/173513), etc.

Comment: Recursively changing the permission with -R as shown in the solution below is the key. Not the solution provided in the similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach was slightly unsuccessful.
Since your bin directory contains another files and directories, **you've to change their permission recursively.**

```
$ find -type d -name bin -exec chmod -R 777 {} \;
```

I Hope, this is what you've expected in return.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, appreciate your support